# snowfalke split into two columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one doubt in snowflake
I have implemente one query in sql server using padindex and need to get
same result in snowflake server
in sql server :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proddetails](
    [Filename] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [pid] [int] NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[proddetails] ([Filename], [pid]) VALUES (N'cinthol_20200108.csv', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[proddetails] ([Filename], [pid]) VALUES (N'pencame_20220309_1.csv', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[proddetails] ([Filename], [pid]) VALUES (N'prodct_20220403.csv', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[proddetails] ([Filename], [pid]) VALUES (N'jain_rav_pan_20220109_1.csv', 4)
based on above data I want out put like below 

in sql server :
 select  pid,filename,substring(filename,0,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',filename)) filename_U
  , cast(cast (substring(filename,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',filename),8) as varchar(8)) as date) filedate_U

FROM [test].[dbo].[proddetails]

pid |filename                     |filename_U     |filedate_U
1   |cinthol_20200108.csv         |cinthol_   |2020-01-08
2   |pencame_20220309_1.csv       |pencame_   |2022-03-09
3   |prodct_20220403.csv          |prodct_    |2022-04-03
4   |jain_rav_pan_20220109_1.csv    |jain_rav_pan_|2022-01-09
```

in snowflake I tried like below

```
    select  pid,filename,substring(filename,0,regexp_instr('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',filename)) filename_U
      , cast(cast (substring(filename,regexp_instr('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',filename),8) as varchar(8)) as date) filedate_U

FROM proddetails 
but above query not giving  exact result .
```

could you please tell me how to write query to achive this task in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
select  pid,filename,  
 regexp_substr(filename, '(.*)[0-9]{8}', 1,1,'e')  filename_U, 
 to_date( regexp_substr(filename, '[0-9]{8}'), 'YYYYMMDD') filedate_U
FROM proddetails;

+-----+-----------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| PID |          FILENAME           |  FILENAME_U   | FILEDATE_U   |
+-----+-----------------------------+---------------+--------------+
|   1 | cinthol_20200108.csv        | cinthol_      | 2020-01-08   |
|   2 | pencame_20220309_1.csv      | pencame_      | 2022-03-09   |
|   3 | prodct_20220403.csv         | prodct_       | 2022-04-03   |
|   4 | jain_rav_pan_20220109_1.csv | jain_rav_pan_ | 2022-01-09   |
+-----+-----------------------------+---------------+--------------+
```